# Installing GTKwave for iMac: Download, untag, and ./configure are O.K -- could not run "make"

Tags: installation

I installed Quartz (new X11), Xcode, and "Icarus Verilog" and they work fine.

I want to install GTKwave to work in TERMINAL.

I have tried countless versions ("download, untar, ./configure, make, make install").

It always fails at step "make" with the error "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."  I see only Makefile.in (but not Makefile in that dir).

Please help to guide me to a working version set to download or show me how to fix it.

Comment: The "configure" command should be generating a Makefile from Makefile.in.  Does the output of configure show any errors?

Comment: Thanks Heptite for your reply.  found error: "missing pkg-config". fixed that by downloading from http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org.   Found new error  "checking for lzma_end in -llzma… no.   LZMA support for VZT is enabled, but xz could not be found".  Downloaded "http://tukaani.org/xz" and installed (ran fine).  Tried ./configure again but same error.   Thanks a lot, Andy.